# How to check type equality between non-template class and template class?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, typechecking, specialization

Suppose I have

```
class A {};

template<typename T, typename U> class Wrapper {};
```

I'm trying to check if the wrapper's first inner type is `A`.

```
typeCheck(new A(), new Wrapper<A,B>);  // expect true
typeCheck(new A(), new Wrapper<C,B>);  // expect false
```

What's the best approach to do it?

---

I've tried template partial specialization but did not have luck.

Here is the code I tried:

```
template<typename T> struct get_inner {
  using type = T;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
struct get_inner<Wrapper<T,U>> {
  using type = T;
}

std::cout<< typeid(get_inner<decltype(new Wrapper<A,B>)>::type);
```

The console shows the same wrapper type instead of the inner type `A`. Is there anything mistake here?

Comment: The type of `new Wrapper<A,B>` is `Wrapper<A,B>*`, not `Wrapper<A,B>`. Do you have [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The console shows the same wrapper type instead of the inner type `A`. Is there anything mistake here?

The type of `new Wrapper<A,B>` is a pointer to the `Wrapper<A,B>`, not `Wrapper` itself. Therefore, it doesn't suit to your specialization, and chose the first base template, where `type` is equal to the passed type, which is `Wrapper<A,B>*`.

Instead, you should have written

```
typename get_inner<Wrapper<A,B>>::type;
```

Note that, the `decltype` is also unnecessary because you are passing the template type itself already.

Since you are trying to see check the type at compile time, I would suggest using `std::is_same` as well. For example

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha
          << std::is_same_v<typename get_inner<Wrapper<A,B>>::type, A>;
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b7566KsPh)

---

> What's the best approach to do it?

Well, there are many ways!

One way is to do, like [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), in standard type traits, you can write traits for this directly:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::false_type, std::true_type

template<typename T> // base template
struct is_inner_type : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, typename U> // specialization
struct is_inner_type<Wrapper<T,U>> {
  static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<A, T>;
};
// variable template for convenience
template<typename ClassType>
inline constexpr bool is_inner_type_v = is_inner_type<ClassType>::value;
```

And you would use it like

```
static_assert(!is_inner_type_v<Wrapper<int, float>>);
static_assert(is_inner_type_v<Wrapper<A, float>>);
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1znnn8WbT)

However, that is not generic enough to change the type to be checked. There, I would suggest something similar to your original implementation.

```
// traits for finding the T & U type!
template <typename T> struct Class;
template <template<typename A, typename B> class Type,  typename A, typename B>
struct Class<Type<A,B>> {
    using T = A;
    // using U = B; // if needed
};
template <typename Type> using  class_t = typename Class<Type>::T;
// template <typename Type> using  class_u = typename Class<Type>::U; // if needed

// variable template for convenience
template<typename ClassType, typename TypeToCheck>
inline constexpr bool is_inner_type_v = std::is_same_v<class_t<ClassType>, TypeToCheck>;
```

I used, template template class specialization, in case you want to make it more generic and use it for other similar class templates.

Comment: Actually, I'm comparing fields of two classes, so there will be different type A. Is it still the best approach to do it?

Comment: Really appreciated. I'm still leaning C++, would you mind explaining the logic of your code? Or why mine does not work? Thanks.